# State of the blog

Tags: discussion, blog

It's been almost a month since the [last blog post](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/04/avengers-vs-x-men-results-winners-announced/) came out. I see 4 old, unfinished, abandonned-looking posts in the queue.

Has the blog activity dried out? To the past contributors: do you have any plan to continue? To others: fancy writing something? To Tony: long time no see, are you still looking for posters?

Comment: As far as I can tell, I no longer have any access to the blog.  If someone that does could allow me access to the drafts I have there, that would be appreciated.

Comment: @TonyMeyer You have access now. Do you still want to run things?

Comment: As I indicated elsewhere, I'm out of ideas.  I don't have any way to get more content, so this should be left to someone that does.  Brett indicated (off-site) that he had plans for this.

Comment: Do you still want that review of "I, Robot: To Protect"? I just finished reading the book.

Answer (score 3):

I've started a draft of a blog post about the 8 Harry Potter films. It is only 6 months after I received the grant.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to do a post on My Canon versus Your Canon, discussing how people view differently the same source material(s). While my fandom is obviously *Harry Potter*, I'm familiar with other universes that I could incorporate into a blog post: SW, ST, LOTR, and any that anyone would be willing to talk to me about (credited, of course). And I'm interested in how the Wikis/Wikias fit in as sources, in relation to canon.

Comment: Is this still something you are considering / working on?

Comment: Did you ever do this?

Answer (score 1):

I plan to write a post as soon as I visit the [Star Wars Identities exhibition](http://www.starwarsidentities.com/) here in Montreal. We were supposed to go here two week ago, but it was sold out. so I don't know when this will happen, but it will be before the end of the summer.

Aside from that, I don't have any idea yet. I may write a post here and there, but nothing regular.