# List of all entries on the Community Blog

Tags: support, blog

This is a list of all entries on [the old Sci Fi Community Blog site](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/) in order from most recent to oldest.  The list is obsolete now, and you should **consult [the complete list of entries on the new blog](https://thesffblog.com/all/) instead**.  All the posts from the old blog has been transferred to the new blog.

- 2016-10-18 [Continuation of the Blog](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/10/continuation-of-the-blog-discussion/)
- 2016-10-05 [Timeless – Pilot](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/10/timeless-pilot/)
- 2016-10-04 [Highlights from 2016 – 3rd Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/10/highlights-from-2016-3rd-quarter/)
- 2016-09-14 [A review of the Stonewylde series](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/09/a-review-of-the-stonewylde-series/)
- 2016-09-06 [Salt Lake Comic Con 2016 Recap](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/09/salt-lake-comic-con-2016-recap/)
- 2016-08-29 [Coverage of Salt Lake Comic Con 2016](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/08/coverage-of-salt-lake-comic-con-2016/)
- 2016-08-27 [The Rise of the Red Shadow – Prequel to the Book of Deacon Trilogy by Joseph Lallo Review](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/08/the-rise-of-the-red-shadow-prequel-to-the-book-of-deacon-trilogy-by-joseph-lallo-review/)
- 2016-08-17 [The Book of Deacon trilogy by Joseph Lallo (spoilers)](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/08/the-book-of-deacon-trilogy-by-joseph-lallo-spoilers/)
- 2016-08-13 [Fant4stic: A Review](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/08/fant4stic-a-review/)
- 2016-08-08 [Star Trek 50 Day 5: Getting deep into DS9, Star Trek writers reflect on the TNG era, and the Star Trek Rat Pack steals the show!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/08/star-trek-50-day-5-getting-deep-into-ds9-star-trek-writers-reflect-on-the-tng-era-and-the-star-trek-rat-pack-steals-the-show/)
- 2016-08-07 [Star Trek 50 Day 4: Captains Shatner, Bakula, and Mulgrew, Bakula’s talking to Fuller, more TNG stars, Walter Koenig, and Star Trek The Concert!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/08/star-trek-50-day-4-captains-shatner-bakula-and-mulgrew-bakulas-talking-to-fuller-more-tng-stars-walter-koenig-and-star-trek-the-concert/)
- 2016-08-06 [Star Trek 50 Day 3: New TOS footage, George Takei, getting candid with TNG and Voyager stars, and a DS9 documentary in the works!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/08/star-trek-50-day-3-new-tos-footage-george-takei-getting-candid-with-tng-and-voyager-stars-and-a-ds9-documentary-in-the-works/)
- 2016-08-05 [Star Trek 50 Day 2: Ferengi fun, Whoopi Goldberg, and Klingon karaoke!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/08/star-trek-50-day-2-ferengi-fun-whoopi-goldberg-and-klingon-karaoke/)
- 2016-08-04 [Star Trek 50 Day 1: Gorn Santa bearing gifts, Leonard Nimoy memories, and a raucous Klingon talk show](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/08/star-trek-50-day-1-gorn-santa-bearing-gifts-leonard-nimoy-memories-and-a-raucous-klingon-talk-show/)
- 2016-08-01 [Coverage of Star Trek 50th Anniversary Celebration for SFF:SE!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/08/coverage-of-star-trek-50th-anniversary-celebration-for-sffse/)
- 2016-07-27 [The Martian Novel by Andy Weir (Spoilers)](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/07/the-martian-novel-by-andy-weir-spoilers/)
- 2016-07-24 [Review – Star Trek Beyond](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/07/star-trek-beyond/)
- 2016-07-20 [Doctor Who isn’t really about time travel](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/07/doctor-who-isnt-really-about-time-travel/)
- 2016-07-13 [Jack’s Bad Movies – The Fifth Wave](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/07/jacks-bad-movies-the-fifth-wave-2/)
- 2016-07-06 [Review of the Duncton Chronicles by William Horwood](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/07/review-of-the-duncton-chronicles-by-william-horwood/)
- 2016-07-05 [Highlights from 2016 – 2nd Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/07/highlights-from-2016-2nd-quarter/)
- 2016-06-29 [Why The Shannara Chronicles by Terry Brooks Is Worth Reading](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/06/why-the-shannara-chronicles-by-terry-brooks-is-worth-reading/)
- 2016-06-22 [The Riyria Revelations by Michael J. Sullivan and why it is the BEST fantasy series EVER!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/06/the-riyria-revelations-by-michael-j-sullivan-and-why-it-is-the-best-fantasy-series-ever/)
- 2016-06-15 [Jack’s Bad Movies – Automata](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/06/jacks-bad-movies-automata/)
- 2016-06-02 [Doctor Who Series 9 Review – Part 2 of 2](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/06/doctor-who-series-9-review-part-2-of-2/)
- 2016-05-31 [The Great Science-Fiction/Fantasy TV Showdown: Final Round](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/05/the-great-science-fictionfantasy-tv-showdown-final-round/)
- 2016-05-26 [X-Men: Apocalypse spoiler-free review](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/05/x-men-apocalypse-spoiler-free-review/)
- 2016-05-23 [The Great Science-Fiction/Fantasy TV Showdown: Round 4](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/05/the-great-science-fictionfantasy-tv-showdown-round-4/)
- 2016-05-12 [A Guide to the Marvel Cinematic Multiverse](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/05/a-guide-to-the-marvel-cinematic-multiverse/)
- 2016-05-10 [The Great Science-Fiction/Fantasy TV Showdown! – Results and Round 3 (2nd Edition)](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/05/the-great-science-fictionfantasy-tv-showdown-results-and-round-3-2nd-edition/)
- 2016-05-02 [The Great Science-Fiction/Fantasy TV Showdown!  – Results and Round Two](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/05/the-great-science-fictionfantasy-tv-showdown-results-and-round-two/)
- 2016-04-25 [The Great Science-Fiction/Fantasy TV Showdown!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/04/the-great-science-fictionfantasy-tv-showdown/)
- 2016-04-19 [Batman v. Superman: Not a Review](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/04/batman-v-superman-not-a-review/)
- 2016-04-07 [Highlights from 2016 – 1st Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/04/highlights-from-2016-1st-quarter/)
- 2016-04-04 [Doctor Who Series 9 Review – Part 1 of 2](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/04/doctor-who-series-9-review-part-1-of-2/)
- 2016-03-28 [Salt Lake Comic Con FanX 2016 – Celebrity Panels](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/03/salt-lake-comic-con-fanx-2016-celebrity-panels/)
- 2016-03-23 [Daredevil Season Two](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/03/daredevil-season-two/)
- 2016-03-15 [Jack’s Bad Movies: Wing Commander](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/03/jacks-bad-movies-wing-commander/)
- 2016-02-15 [Jack’s Bad Movies: Highlander II: The Quickening](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/02/jacks-bad-movies-highlander-ii-the-quickening/)
- 2016-02-12 [Deadpool Review](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/02/deadpool-review/)
- 2016-02-08 [Lego Marvel’s Avengers – A First Look](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/02/lego-marvels-avengers-a-first-look/)
- 2016-01-20 [The 13 Commandments from the TNG Bible.](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/01/the-13-commandments-from-the-tng-bible/)
- 2016-01-12 [On The Death of a Science Fiction Icon:  A Celebration of David Bowie’s Life and Legacy](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/01/on-the-death-of-a-science-fiction-icon-a-celebration-of-david-bowies-life-and-legacy/)
- 2016-01-04 [Highlights from 2015 – 4th Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/01/highlights-from-2015-4th-quarter/)
- 2015-11-27 [Jessica Jones season one review](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/11/jessica-jones-season-one-review/)
- 2015-11-10 [A Guide To The DC Cinematic Multiverse](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/11/a-guide-to-the-dc-cinematic-multiverse/)
- 2015-10-27 [Story where the number 3 is the monster: Finally Answered!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/10/story-where-the-number-3-is-the-monster-finally-answered/)
- 2015-10-02 [Highlights from 2015 – 3rd Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/10/highlights-from-2015-3rd-quarter/)
- 2015-09-27 [Salt Lake Comic Con 2015 Summary](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/09/salt-lake-comic-con-2015-summary/)
- 2015-09-22 [Minority Report – Pilot](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/09/minority-report-pilot/)
- 2015-08-25 [Live Chat: The Day the Earth Stood Still (1951)](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/08/live-chat-the-day-the-earth-stood-still-1951/)
- 2015-08-10 [Fantastic Four: A (mildly spoilery) review!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/08/fantastic-four-a-mildly-spoilery-review/)
- 2015-07-31 [Jack’s Bad Movies – Left Behind](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/07/jacks-bad-movies-left-behind/)
- 2015-07-28 [The Solarian War Saga](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/07/the-solarian-war-saga/)
- 2015-07-20 [Ant-Man: A (mildly spoilery) review!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/07/ant-man-a-mildly-spoilery-review/)
- 2015-07-17 [Revisiting The Terminator](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/07/revisiting-the-terminator/)
- 2015-07-06 [Highlights from 2015 – 2nd Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/07/highlights-from-2015-2nd-quarter/)
- 2015-06-25 [Gorilla vs. Shark? Not so fast…](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/06/gorilla-vs-shark-not-so-fast/)
- 2015-06-17 [Mutants in the Marvel Universe](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/06/mutants-in-the-marvel-universe/)
- 2015-06-14 [Jack’s Bad Movies – Jinn](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/06/jacks-bad-movies-jinn/)
- 2015-05-29 [Stitchers – Early Episode 1 Release](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/05/stitchers-early-episode-1-release/)
- 2015-05-26 [Supergirl “leaked Pilot” – An almost completely spoiler-free review](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/05/supergirl-leaked-pilot-an-almost-completely-spoiler-free-review/)
- 2015-04-09 [Highlights from 2015 – 1st Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/04/highlights-from-2014-1st-quarter-2/)
- 2015-03-23 [Jack’s Bad Movies – Yor, the Hunter from the Future](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/03/jacks-bad-movies-yor-the-hunter-from-the-future/)
- 2015-03-13 [Review – Cinderella](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/03/cinderella-review/)
- 2015-02-11 [Science Fiction, Fantasy and Genre](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/02/science-fiction-fantasy-and-genre/)
- 2015-02-04 [Salt Lake Comic Con FanX 2015 – Heroes, Villains, and Anti-Heroes in Harry Potter: Who’s Who? Panel](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/02/salt-lake-comic-con-fanx-2015-heroes-villains-and-anti-heroes-in-harry-potter-whos-who-panel/)
- 2015-02-03 [Salt Lake Comic Con FanX 2015 – KIDCON and Disney Princesses](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/02/salt-lake-comic-con-fanx-2015-kidcon-and-disney-princesses/)
- 2015-02-02 [Featured Answer: How long was Bill Murray’s character supposed to be in a time loop in the film “Groundhog Day”?](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/02/featured-question-how-long-was-bill-murrays-character-supposed-to-be-in-a-time-loop-in-the-film-groundhog-day/)
- 2015-01-31 [Salt Lake Comic Con FanX 2015 – Tom Felton Panel](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/01/salt-lake-comic-con-fanx-2015-tom-felton-panel/)
- 2015-01-28 [The (new) Star Wars Canon guide](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/01/the-new-star-wars-canon-guide/)
- 2015-01-07 [Agent Carter – Pilot Episode](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/01/agent-carter-pilot-episode/)
- 2015-01-06 [Highlights from 2014 – 4th Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/01/highlights-from-2014-4th-quarter/)
- 2014-12-31 [Technologies We Should Have In 2015](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/12/technologies-we-should-have-in-2015/)
- 2014-12-29 [Jack’s Bad Movies – AE: Apocalypse Earth](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/12/jacks-bad-movies-ae-apocalypse-earth/)
- 2014-12-02 [Doom Star Series (books)](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/12/doom-star-series-books/)
- 2014-11-10 [Detective Comics #27 – Introduction of the Batman](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/11/detective-comics-27-introduction-of-the-batman/)
- 2014-11-01 [Science Fiction Technologies that People are Hoping for in Their Lifetime](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/11/science-fiction-technologies-that-people-are-hoping-for-in-their-lifetime/)
- 2014-10-15 [Favorite Questions and Answers of All Time](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/10/favorite-questions-and-answers-of-all-time/)
- 2014-10-08 [The Flash – Pilot Episode](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/10/the-flash-pilot-episode/)
- 2014-10-06 [Highlights from 2014 – 3rd Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/10/highlights-from-2014-3rd-quarter/)
- 2014-09-10 [Salt Lake Comic Con 2014 Report](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/09/salt-lake-comic-con-overall/)
- 2014-09-08 [Salt Lake Comic Con 2014 – Marvel Movies Phase III Panel](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/09/salt-lake-comic-con-marvel-movies-phase-iii-panel/)
- 2014-07-22 [Starship Troopers – The Mobile Infantry definitely does not accept Hippies!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/07/starship-troopers-the-mobile-infantry-definitely-does-not-accept-hippies/)
- 2014-07-15 [Highlights from 2014 – 2nd Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/07/highlights-from-2014-2nd-quarter/)
- 2014-07-02 [The First Formic War (Ender’s Game Prequel Trilogy)](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/07/the-first-formic-war-enders-game-prequel-trilogy/)
- 2014-04-25 [Salt Lake Comic Con Fan Xperience](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/04/salt-lake-comic-con-fan-xperience/)
- 2014-04-10 [Highlights from 2014 – 1st Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/04/highlights-from-2014-1st-quarter/)
- 2014-03-20 [The 100 – Pilot Episode](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/03/the-100-pilot-episode/)
- 2014-03-05 [Movies With Time-Traveling Robots](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/03/movies-with-time-traveling-robots/)
- 2014-01-14 [Highlights from 2013 – 4th Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/01/highlights-from-2013-4th-quarter/)
- 2013-12-27 [TV Shows with a Supernatural Theme](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/12/tv-shows-with-a-supernatural-theme/)
- 2013-12-03 [Review – Frozen](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/12/review-frozen/)
- 2013-11-21 [Review – Thor: The Dark World](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/11/review-thor-the-dark-world/)
- 2013-11-08 [Guide to either loving or hating Ender’s Game (film)](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/11/guide-to-either-loving-or-hating-enders-game-film/)
- 2013-10-08 [Highlights from 2013 – 3rd Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/10/highlights-from-2013-3rd-quarter/)
- 2013-09-10 [Live Chat: Star Trek TOS “Space Seed”](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/live-chat-star-trek-tos-space-seed/)
- 2013-07-26 [Review – Turbo](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/07/review-turbo/)
- 2013-07-19 [Review – World War Z](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/07/review-world-war-zed/)
- 2013-07-02 [Highlights from 2013 – 2nd Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/07/highlights-from-2013-2nd-quarter/)
- 2013-06-25 [Review – Man Of Steel](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/06/man-of-steel/)
- 2013-05-23 [Review: Iron Man 3](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/review-iron-man-3/)
- 2013-04-08 [Highlights from 2013 – 1st Quarter](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/04/highlights-from-2013-1st-quarter/)
- 2013-04-04 [Reviews: The Croods](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/04/reviews-the-croods/)
- 2012-10-14 [Brickcon 2012](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/brickcon-2012/)
- 2012-09-12 [Space Saga – Chapter 1: The accident](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/space-saga-chapter-1-the-accident/)
- 2012-08-28 [Star Wars Identities : The Exhibition](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/star-wars-identities-the-exhibition/)
- 2012-08-09 [Live Chat – Star Trek TOS “And The Children Shall Lead”](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/live-chat-star-trek-tos-and-the-children-shall-lead/)
- 2012-06-27 [HeroesCon 2012 Report](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/heroescon-2012-report/)
- 2012-05-31 [Harry Potter Movie Marathon Highlights](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/05/harry-potter-movie-marathon-highlights/)
- 2012-04-20 [Avengers vs. X-Men results! Winners announced!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/04/avengers-vs-x-men-results-winners-announced/)
- 2012-04-18 [Topic of the Week Contest: The Legend of Korra](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/04/topic-of-the-week-contest-the-legend-of-korra/)
- 2012-04-04 [Avengers vs. X-Men is here!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/04/avengers-vs-x-men-is-here/)
- 2012-04-01 [A month of comic exploration](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/04/a-month-of-comic-exploration/)
- 2012-03-07 [Stack Exchange is giving away sets of Game of Thrones: Season 1 on Blu-Ray and DVD!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/stack-exchange-is-giving-away-sets-of-game-of-thrones-season-1-on-blu-ray-and-dvd/)
- 2012-03-05 [SciFi.StackExchange in Practical Use – A newcomer’s journey to Doctor Who.](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/scifi-stackexchange-in-practical-use-a-newcomers-journey-to-doctor-who/)
- 2012-03-01 [The Last Question](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/the-last-question/)
- 2012-02-29 [New Mid-season Sci-fi & Fantasy TV](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/02/new-mid-season-sci-fi-fantasy-tv/)
- 2012-01-27 [Moderator Elections](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/01/moderator-elections/)
- 2011-12-22 [The Dark Mirror / Blade of Fortriu](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/12/the-dark-mirror-blade-of-fortriu/)
- 2011-12-15 [Featured Question: E.T. & Star Wars](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/12/featured-question-e-t-star-wars/)
- 2011-12-13 [Launch!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/12/launch/)
- 2011-12-08 [Movies Sister Site Launches](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/12/movies-sister-site-launches/)
- 2011-10-25 [SciFi.StackExchange in Practical Use – In what order should the Star Wars movies be watched?](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/scifi-stackexchange-in-practical-use-in-what-order-should-the-star-wars-movies-be-watched/)
- 2011-10-24 [Sci-Fi Stack Exchange at New York Comic Con](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/sci-fi-stack-exchange-at-new-york-comic/)
- 2011-10-18 [Re-evaluating the end of “Planetary”](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/re-evaluating-the-end-of-planetary/)
- 2011-10-07 [Q&A with Jim Gibbons of Dark Horse Comics](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/qa-with-jim-gibbons-of-dark-horse-comics/)
- 2011-10-06 [Featured Question: In The Lord of the Rings, what important background information is contained in the poems?](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/featured-question-in-the-lord-of-the-rings-what-important-background-information-is-contained-in-the-poems/)
- 2011-10-03 [Stack Exchange is giving away 3-day passes to New York Comic Con](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/nyccse/)
- 2011-09-29 [Contagion – ‘Jaws’ for the Flu](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/contagion-jaws-for-the-flu/)
- 2011-09-25 [Review: Roger Zelazny, A Night in the Lonesome October](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/review-roger-zelazny-a-night-in-the-lonesome-october/)
- 2011-09-25 [Amazon Kindle now servicing over 11,000 public libraries](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/amazon-kindle-now-servicing-over-11000-public-libraries/)
- 2011-09-23 [The Sci-fi & Fantasy Fall 2011 TV Season](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/the-sci-fi-fantasy-fall-2011-tv-season/)
- 2011-09-19 [Stack Exchange Helps Out a Superman Fan](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/stack-exchange-helps-out-a-superman-fan/)
- 2011-09-15 [DC’s new 52](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/dcs-new-52/)
- 2011-09-13 [Digital Vs. Physical – How do digital comics stand up to the tried and true?](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/digital-vs-physical-%e2%80%93-how-do-digital-comics-stand-up-to-the-tried-and-true/)
- 2011-09-10 [Review: The Throne of Fire, by Rick Riordan](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/review-the-throne-of-fire-by-rick-riordan/)
- 2011-09-07 [Comic Recommendation: Y: The Last Man](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/comic-recommendation-y-the-last-man/)
- 2011-09-05 [Interview: Jason Snell, host of The Incomparable SF&F Podcast](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/interview-jason-snell-host-of-the-incomparable-sff-podcast/)
- 2011-09-03 [What has a love of science-fiction done for me?](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/what-has-a-love-of-science-fiction-done-for-me/)
- 2011-09-01 [@stackscifi improvements](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/stackscifi-improvements/)
- 2011-08-26 [Lessons Learned: Lord of the Rings](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/lessons_learn_lot/)
- 2011-08-24 [Review of Another Earth](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/review-of-another-earth/)
- 2011-08-24 [Literature Sister Site Launches](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/literature-sister-site-launches/)
- 2011-08-22 [iPad PADD application: disappointing](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/ipad-padd-application-disappointing/)
- 2011-08-22 [Elvis Has Left the Building](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/elvis-has-left-the-building/)
- 2011-08-20 [The Hugo Awards: Live Coverage](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/the-hugo-awards-live-coverage/)
- 2011-08-20 [Costumes Everywhere](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/costumes-everywhere/)
- 2011-08-19 [Instant Art!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/instant-art/)
- 2011-08-19 [Fannish Humor](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/fannish-humor/)
- 2011-08-18 [Tricky Pixie in Concert](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/tricky-pixie-in-concert/)
- 2011-08-18 [Steve Jackson at Worldcon](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/steve-jackson-at-worldcon/)
- 2011-08-17 [Welcome to Worldcon!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/welcome-to-worldcon/)
- 2011-08-14 [Stack Exchange is going to Worldcon!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/stack-exchange-is-going-to-worldcon/)
- 2011-08-13 [Featured Question: Why Do We Hear Leia’s Theme During Kenobi’s Death](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/featured-question-why-do-we-hear-leias-theme-during-kenobis-death/)
- 2011-08-12 [Artemis Fowl](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/artemis-fowl/)

I post this list because it seems impossible to ask the Wordpress-based blog directly for such a list.  Thanks to Rand al'Thor for the idea to post this on meta.

<s>If a new blog entry is posted, feel free to add the link into this post.</s>

Comment: Great job. However, wouldn't it be better if you were to make this a community wiki given that you are open to community updating this post?

Comment: @Aegon: does the Meta even have community wiki posts? If so, how do they work?

Comment: Answers can be made CW by the OP. For Questions I think, only mods have that power.

Comment: I like it, I wish it included the authors, but when we move to a new site, these links will all have to be updated,

Comment: @JackBNimble: I could include the authors if you want, but you'd have to decide on the format.  Note that many of the titles are already long, so adding authors will cause a lot of entries to get broken to two lines, at least for people like me who use large fonts.

Comment: It turns out it's not easy to include the authors, because that runs to the question body length limit.

Comment: The blog post about Star Wars canon is awesome. The others...meh :-)

Comment: @Valorum Thank you for that unbiased opinion. Perhaps that post should be updated to reflect new media releases.

Comment: Wordpress will allow you to list all of your posts from a site with just a few commands. I have used it personally and I know it works: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-all-your-wordpress-posts-on-one-page/

Comment: @JackBNimble - Not especially needed. As I've pointed out in the comments below it, everything published after the blog post was written is part of the Star Wars canon.

Comment: Great, thanks for making this post! A couple of points: 1) As @Aegon suggested, this should probably be CW so that anyone can edit it (note that suggested edits for <2k rep users are disabled on meta). 2) If you're running close to the question body length limit, it might be a good idea to find a different way to format the list so it won't overrun when new posts are made. Perhaps include all title text but links only to the lists by [month](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/06/) or [topic](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/category/conventions/)?

Comment: (Of course, this post will need to be heavily edited when we change the blog platform, so there's no point in spending much time agonising over formatting decisions at this point.)

Comment: So what's the question here? Or are we now just using meta as a notes repository and for every possible thing where we just want to save information?

Comment: Voting to close this question as a duplicate of [http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/archive/](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/archive/)

Comment: @KutuluMike that page lists only lets me jump to specific months. I don't see a way there to list all articles with their titles and links. Is there?

Comment: @phantom42: Yes, at least if the notes are public ones that people other than me might want to use. This is a workaround for the blog site not being able to do such a basic thing as showing me the list of entries.

Comment: @phantom42: I could make the question "Where can I find a list of all entries on the Sci Fi SE Blog?" and give the list in an answer if that would make this more acceptible.

Comment: Just putting this out there, but it'd be trivial to get this implemented on the new site.

Comment: @CreationEdge: yes, it's trivial to implement, which is why it's annoying that practically no Wordpress or Blogger blog out there implements it.

Comment: Well, there's not much need. It steals page hits and makes it easier for bots to pull content. Those aren't things people making money or recognition off blogs want.

Comment: Because new posts from off-site blogs don't show up in that "events" box on the front page, on Worldbuilding we're using a [meta post](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/4037/28) to announce each new post, with the answer containing a complete list.  We then create a community event to point to that meta post when there's a new blog post, to get it onto the front page.  Just sharing in case that helps you with this effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This page has the complete list by date and title:

http://thesffblog.com/all/

Formatting is not necessarily finalized, but the list is automatically generated.

---

Feel free to comment if there are other specific things you'd prefer to see on this page, such as Author.

The [Archive page](http://thesffblog.com/archive/) continues to break down posts by month/topic/etc.

"All Posts Page" is now a link at the top of the Archive.

Comment: Could you add some obvious link to that list page from the blog or from the archive page?  Currently I can find it only because this answer links to it.

Comment: @b_jonas Yes. The design and layout is still being finalized, but I'll probably add it to the archive page

Comment: @b_jonas The URL has been updated, just FYI