# What should we call our blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

EDIT: the general opinion (here and elsewhere) was to stick to something simple and descriptive; looking through the unregistered domain options, we have gone with [thesffblog.com](http://thesffblog.com/). We'll have more details soon.

Technically, the blog is currently named: 
"The Science Fiction & Fantasy Community Blog: We Have a Blog!"

As this was essentially what the blog was already named, and keeping it is in line with the votes in the other blog thread about keeping the site as same as possible.

Although the full title doesn't necessarily show up on the site, it will show up in the browser title.

---

It seems very likely that we're going to have to move our blog off-site, as it [has been noted](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10256/do-we-want-to-continue-having-a-community-blog) that blogoverflow is shutting down soon. We're still deciding if we want to have one but the general consensus is tending towards yes.

We are working on the mechanics of where to put it and how to migrate, but in the mean time, something we need to figure out is what to *call* it. Since that may take some time to settle on a name, I figured we may as well get started bickering now :)

Currently, our leading contender is Blogger (we have a proof-of-concept working now; anyone interested can join us in the [blog chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1364/sff-blog-discussion)). Alternatives include Medium and Wordpress.com. In any case, though, we have two ways to identify the blog:

- A "subdomain" or "site name" for the blog as hosted on the main site, e.g. `ourblog.blogspot.com`
- A custom domain name we can redirect at the blog, e.g. `www.sffblog.org`.

Obviously, our name is going to be limited to those things that are still available, so we'll need to come up with several alternatives until we come up with one that's available. Ideally we'd have the same blog name and custom domain name but that's not *required*.

If anyone has any suggestions, just leave them below. I'll check to see what's available where and hopefully one will bubble up to the top.

---

FOR REFERENCE: I already checked some of the obvious ones: `sffantasy`, `sfandfantasy`, `scififantasy`, and `scifiandfantasy` are all taken on Blogger and Wordpress, as are the `.com` domains. Medium is more flexible with "publication names" if we're willing to use one that isn't a valid domain name.

As an example of how the naming *might* work, the proof-of-concept we are playing with on Blogger is currently called [`http://agentsofnothing.blogspot.com`](http://agentsofnothing.blogspot.com) and is also available at [`http://sffblog.kutulu.org`](http://sffblog.kutulu.org)

Comment: Would we be permitted to use the SE name in the blog’s title at all, or would that be Strictly Prohibited?

Comment: I've asked that; we don't have an official answer but it seems likely that we can. [Worldbuilding's blog](https://medium.com/universe-factory) is clear that it's the blog for a stack exchange site.

Comment: "Worldbuilding's blog is clear that it's the blog for a stack exchange site. " Based on previous comments from staff, I find this interesting and a little surprising.

Comment: How about Bloggy McBlogface? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Science Fiction and Fantasy Blog

Very simple, very easy to search for.

Comment: Maybe an "SE" somewhere in there? After all, it [wouldn't be the only sci-fi & fantasy blog on the internet](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/blog/sci-fi-fantasy/).

Comment: @Randal'Thor No, but there's another answer that suggests that. The fact that others exist doesn't mean we can't sell to ourselves that we're the definitive one. Adding SE, to me, advertises that we're associated with SE, and we won't be. Aside from current contributors originating from here, and current readership base, there's nothing that particularly makes it geared towards SE aside from the quarterly roundups.

Comment: @Randal'Thor we are the only SFF blog on the internet. Period.

Comment: @JackBNimble Because all the other ones are dead to you?

Answer (score 7):

You should name it "We Have a Blog" with the subtitle "The Sci Fi and Fantasy Stack Exchange Blog".

Comment: http://wehaveablog.blogspot.com/ is taken, as is wehaveablog.com. :(

Comment: The address should be informative anyway. SFFSEblog.com or whatever. Though I'm sure those guys all use the name as their name... hrm.

Comment: `wehasablog.com` is available, as is `wehavea-scifi-blog.com`

Answer (score 3):

Call the blog ***Science Fiction & Fantasy Community Blog***, since that's what it's currently called.  (The title says "Stack Exchange Science Fiction & Fantasy Blog:" but the big image logo says "Science Fiction & Fantasy Community Blog" on the image and "site title" as the alt text.)  For the domain name, choose domain names with `scificommunity` as one of the components, such as `scificommunity.blogspot.com` or `www.scificommunity.org`.

(As an alternative, try to register the `scifi.org` domain name if it's not taken yet, since it's a nice short and easy to remember domain name.)

Comment: scifi.org is taken :-)

Comment: @Valorum scifi.org seems unused to me, but maybe it is owned already only it doesn't point anywhere. But then, any domain I mention in a public post will be taken quickly by domain name squatters, so it's sort of futile to suggest anything here.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not too late, I will throw in the ***Scientifically Fantastic Blog***

This combines science, fantasy, and the SE model of having fact/expert based answers!

Comment: Stealer of ideas! LMAO

Answer (score -1):

Can't we keep using the old domain, and have Stack Exchange point it at an off-site blog?

This is certainly doable, the question is if the SE team wants to do that.

Comment: Even if SE redirects from http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/ to the new blog, the URL is going to change when it hits the new site. So, regardless, a new domain is going to be used.

Comment: @SQB the blog still needs a "name" just to create it, though people may never see it if we have a custom domain pointed to it. if SE is willing to keep paying for and maintaining the blogoverflow domain that would otherwise work but I suspect they won't...

Comment: I don't think blogoverflow (for the sake of the podcast and stuff) is going away, so the subdomain should be an easy thing

Answer (score -1):

What about The Definitive SF&F Blog? It is setting it up to be better than others (definitive) and it is exactly what we are.. a Science-Fiction & Fantasy Blog?

Answer (score -2):

It shouldn't be a catchy yet cryptic (or worse off, specific-to-franchise-and-offputting-to-non-fans) name. It should be self-documenting, as all good identifiers are.

SpeculativeFictionSEBlog

or

SpeculativeFictionStackExhangeBlog

or

SciFiAndFantasyStackExchangeBlog

or

SciFiAndFantasySEBlog

*("Blog" suffixes are optional; if blogger.com is used as main domain).*

Comment: Indeed, I'd also beware of calling it after an inside joke that about ~20 chat and meta users even know about.

Comment: I'm only against this because I don't feel like throwing in "SE" is necessary. Sure, it started here, and it's got the SE community around it. But, they're giving us the boot and are only going to be loosely associated with it from hereon out.

Comment: the upside of tacking "SE" onto it, more likely to be available. downside, it looks silly.