# Meta sci-fi blog link wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, hyperlinks

On the main [Sci-Fi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) site is this link:

- [blog](https://thesffblog.com/?blb=1)

which goes (correctly) to the [Science Fiction & Fantasy Blog](https://thesffblog.com/?blb=1).

[image: Blog link]

At the bottom of this (meta) page the link is:

- [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/?blb=1)

which goes to the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) blog.

Looks like the link on this page a bug.

Comment: Good catch! I'm pleasantly surprised to find that the blog link on the main site still goes to our now-unofficial site blog; here's hoping SE's solution to this won't be to make both links go to the SO blog.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thanks. Why is our blog unofficial?

Comment: It's no longer supported by Stack Exchange, and is being run and even hosted just by a few SFF community members. See [this meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10256/31394).

Comment: Are you sure the link at the bottom of the page (right above where all the other sites are listed and where there are links to the company and such) going to the main SO blog isn't intentional?

Comment: Actually I think this may have always been the case, and therefore [meta-tag:status-bydesign] rather than an artefact of the recent changes in both the blog URL and the meta site URL. See Wayback Machine captures of [meta](http://web.archive.org/web/20130303081453/http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/) and [main](http://web.archive.org/web/20140302164344/http://scifi.stackexchange.com/) from years ago - the links in the footer were still different from each other, even then.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: or maybe the bug has just been in there and undetected for a really long time!

Comment: Could you maybe add a little more context and detail *where* that link "on the main site" is taken from? Is it from the drop-down menu? From the side-bar? Or from the same bottom section you inspected on meta?

Comment: @TARS --- done!

Comment: Thank you, the question makes quite a bit more sense now and I see why that's an inconsistency.

Comment: @Wikis Maybe! In any case, I've pinged an SE employee about this, so I guess we just wait for them to respond, as they're the only people who can do anything about it.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - have you heard back? Is there anything we can do or just wait? Seems like a trivial thing to resolve... shouldn't take this long.

Comment: @Wikis Judging from the edit history of your question, and the two deleted answers below, the CMs/devs *are* aware of this issue and have been looking into it, but have got somewhat confused and aren't quite sure what they're doing. I guess we wait for them to work it out.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - thanks. I'm not sure what there is to get confused about ... I think it is clear to understand and trivial to solve?!

Comment: Traditionally the blog link at the bottom linked to the scifi.blogoverflow.com, and we had hoped for it to link to the new location thesffblog.com. Additionally, the blog has traditionally fed the "Featured" box, and would like that to continue to work as well.

Answer (score 1):

The official-looking links in the footer were never intended to point off-site; that worked *briefly* for a short time on the main site because it was still pointing to the old Blog Overflow site, which was redirecting to the off-site blog...

The redirect still exists, but the footer no longer links to it, on the main site or on meta.

As a general rule, **we're not going to send folks off-site via an official-looking link** unless there's [an amusing 10-hour YouTube video on the other end](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxopViU98Xo).

The footer is kind of a lousy way to promote the blog anyway. I'm not entirely sure why there's even a link to the *system blog* in the footer, although perhaps it helps with SEO in some way; most of the links there are far more utilitarian - the equivalent of the fine print on the inside cover of a magazine: great when you want to know where to send angry letters to the editor, but not where you go looking for articles.

I prefer the way Worldbuilding does it: a meta post corresponding to the latest post, with an event that announces it on the sidebar for some length of time. That gives y'all complete control over how long each post is promoted, while giving readers some context before they end up off site (and a convenient way to post feedback if there's a problem). See: [How can we improve blog promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285998/how-can-we-improve-blog-promotion)

Comment: I believe the correct 10-hour YouTube video video to link on this stack is [the cantina song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWO5Ai_a80M)

Comment: The footer was what first led me to this site (from Maths.SE) and caused me to actually set up an SE account and start posting. It's not all that useless.

Comment: Note that community events have to be created and managed by moderators; you can't have users help out with this part.  If your blog maintainers are also mods then that works fine; if not, y'all will need to do some coordination.

Comment: @ed False, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ep_aPSrwYI) is the correct one for this site!

Comment: I can't believe you overlooked [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4J9-CQXdPk), @Mooz.

Comment: @Mooz Incorrect, you should know as a resident Tolkien-ite, I know all the "Lord of the Rings" 10-hour Youtube videos are abominations created by the Tyrant *Peter Jackson*. The glorious creation that is A New Hope however. Is the perfect 10-hour Youtube video for our site.